# Chrome Extension: Stop all tabs and windows except for active one and if playing audio

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome-extension, tabs, exit

How do I stop all tabs and windows except for active ones and the ones playing audio? I found this to help:

> If you want something with a content script to happen always, you define it in >the manifest:
>
> If your content script's code should always be injected, register it in the >extension manifest using the content_scripts field

```
"content_scripts" : [{
  "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
  "js": ["stop.js"],
  "run_at": "document_start"
}],
```

With that, you know that stop.js is loaded alongside every page at the beginning of the page load. Then you can implement your logic. Dead-simple solution:

```
// stop.js
setTimeout(() => {window.stop()}, 10000);
```

The problem is: there is no mention of active windows, active tabs, tabs or active audio.  I've been wanting to do this for some time.  Basically, websites nowdays are alive (javascript overflow) and dark humour permitting, I want them dead once they are done loading with the exception of audio/video sites (javascript termination). There was also mention of:

> You may also want to consider adding "all_frames": true to the content script >declaration if you want this to also happen in sub-frames.

So would it look like this:

```
"content_scripts" : [{
  "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
  "js": ["stop.js"],
  "run_at": "document_start"
  "all_frames": true
}],
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API)
and especially the `document.hidden` property in your script to know if the current tab is visible to prevent "stopping" it:

> **Document.hidden** (Read only)
>   Returns true if the page is in a state considered to be hidden to the user, and false otherwise.

This API also provides events to detect page visibility change in case you want to react to them (switch between tabs).

Regarding tabs playing audio, I would suggest you to add a background script to your extension
and send it [messages](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging) from the tabs to check which ones are playing audio, using the [chrome.tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) API.
The API provides a boolean `audible` property, as described below:

> Whether the tab has produced sound over the past couple of seconds (but it might not be heard if also muted). Equivalent to whether the speaker audio indicator is showing.

You could also have a look at the code of the [Great Suspender Chrome extension](https://github.com/deanoemcke/thegreatsuspender), you may find some useful code.